# How using a string text and lists could I replace certain characters in that specific string text?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace

So I have a string text, and within that string text certain characters in certain words are replaced with others (`typo_text`). For example: *"USA, Germany, the European Commission, Japan, and Canada to fund the development and equitable rollout of the tests."* This would be the correct format but currently instead im given this, *"XSX, Gxrmxny, the European Commission, Jxpxn, and Cxnxdx to fund the development and equitable rollout of the tests, treatments and vaccines needed to end the acute phase of the COVID-19 pandemic.* So far this code just prints the mistaken text and not the corrected version.

```
def corrected_string(test_str, K):
    # string of vowels
    typo_text= "XSX, Gxrmxny, the European Commission, Jxpxn, and Cxnxdx to fund the development and equitable rollout of the tests"
    word = 'x'
    vowels='aeiou'
    # iterating to check vowels in string
    for ele in vowels:
        # replacing vowel with the specified character
        test_str = test_str.replace(ele, K)
    return test_str
# Driver Code
# input string
input_str = typo_text
```

I have two lists with the countries and mistakes but don't know how to implement those in my code exactly.

```
name_G7_countries = ['Canada', 'France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'UK', 'USA']
mistake =  ['Cxnxdx', 'Frxncx', 'Gxrmxny', 'Xtxly', 'Jxpxn','XK', 'XSX']
```